# getting data into Python on an organized dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have `data` like this below that is a dictionary inside a list. There is 3 unique "points" which is a space temperature float, a space temperature setpoint float, and a cooling air flow setpoint float. Any chance someone could give me a tip on how two get this into Pandas df in an organized format?

By organized I am trying to build the pandas data frame based on an index with 4 columns.

`index=['Zone_Temps','Zone_Temp_Setpoints','Max_Clg_Flow','VAV_ID']`

This is the data

```
data = [{'slipstream_internal/slipstream_hq/27/ZN-T': 72.2730712890625, 'slipstream_internal/slipstream_hq/27/ZN-SP': 70.0, 'slipstream_internal/slipstream_hq/27/CLG-MAXFLOW': 580.0, 'slipstream_internal/slipstream_hq/29/ZN-T': 73.02095794677734, 'slipstream_internal/slipstream_hq/29/ZN-SP': 69.75, 'slipstream_internal/slipstream_hq/29/CLG-MAXFLOW': 1400.0, 'slipstream_internal/slipstream_hq/30/ZN-T': 71.63856506347656, 'slipstream_internal/slipstream_hq/30/ZN-SP': 72.0, 'slipstream_internal/slipstream_hq/30/CLG-MAXFLOW': 918.0, 'slipstream_internal/slipstream_hq/12028/Space Temperature Local': 23.014436721801758, 'slipstream_internal/slipstream_hq/12028/Space Temperature Setpoint Active': 23.329999923706055, 'slipstream_internal/slipstream_hq/12028/Air Flow Setpoint Maximum': 660.725830078125, 'slipstream_internal/slipstream_hq/12032/Space Temperature Local': 22.482545852661133, 'slipstream_internal/slipstream_hq/12032/Space Temperature Setpoint Active': 22.307844161987305, 'slipstream_internal/slipstream_hq/12032/Air Flow Setpoint Maximum': 471.9469909667969, 'slipstream_internal/slipstream_hq/12033/Space Temperature Local': 22.3153133392334, 'slipstream_internal/slipstream_hq/12033/Space Temperature Setpoint Active': 22.698659896850586, 'slipstream_internal/slipstream_hq/12033/Air Flow Setpoint Maximum': 235.97349548339844}, {}]
```

How do I get the `data` into a pandas df?
Some caveats:

The `Zone_Temps` float is the string that contains a `ZN-T` at the end of the string or `Space Temperature Local`. The `Zone_Temp_Setpoints` float that contains `ZN-SP` or `Space Temperature Setpoint Active` at the end. The `Max_Clg_Flow` float contains `CLG-MAXFLOW` or `Air Flow Setpoint Maximum` at the end. And this below would be the `VAV_ID` which is a string containing this info, the number at the end (`27`) is the unique identifier:

`slipstream_internal/slipstream_hq/27/`

Any tips greatly appreciated sorry if the description of what I am looking for is too vague.

Comment: Parse your key to columns that you want organised in a dictionary, then construct your DataFrame. I usually use an internal representation like `pd.DataFrame([ { 'col1': 'val1', 'col2': 'val2' }, { 'col1': 'val3', 'col2': 'val4' } ])` for the constructor.

Comment: I am drawing a blank on how to do this... Any links or anything I can reference as an example?

Comment: I don't understand how do you need the output df? Do you need a df only with the four columns you mentioned, I mean (`Zone_Temps`,`Zone_Temp_Setpoints`,`Max_Clg_Flow`,`VAV_ID`)?

Comment: yes exactly.....

Comment: `df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(temps, temp_setpoints, flows, names)),
                       columns=['Zone_Temps','Zone_Temp_Setpoints','Air_Flows','VAV_ID'])`

Comment: I am trying to figure out a way to do something that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First let’s pass everything as a list of flat lists to `pd.DataFrame`, splitting the keys on `/` to make them into different columns:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([[*key.split('/'), value]
... for dictionary in data for key, value in dictionary.items()])
>>> df
                      0              1      2                                  3            4
0   slipstream_internal  slipstream_hq     27                               ZN-T    72.273071
1   slipstream_internal  slipstream_hq     27                              ZN-SP    70.000000
2   slipstream_internal  slipstream_hq     27                        CLG-MAXFLOW   580.000000
3   slipstream_internal  slipstream_hq     29                               ZN-T    73.020958
4   slipstream_internal  slipstream_hq     29                              ZN-SP    69.750000
5   slipstream_internal  slipstream_hq     29                        CLG-MAXFLOW  1400.000000
6   slipstream_internal  slipstream_hq     30                               ZN-T    71.638565
7   slipstream_internal  slipstream_hq     30                              ZN-SP    72.000000
8   slipstream_internal  slipstream_hq     30                        CLG-MAXFLOW   918.000000
9   slipstream_internal  slipstream_hq  12028            Space Temperature Local    23.014437
10  slipstream_internal  slipstream_hq  12028  Space Temperature Setpoint Active    23.330000
11  slipstream_internal  slipstream_hq  12028          Air Flow Setpoint Maximum   660.725830
12  slipstream_internal  slipstream_hq  12032            Space Temperature Local    22.482546
13  slipstream_internal  slipstream_hq  12032  Space Temperature Setpoint Active    22.307844
14  slipstream_internal  slipstream_hq  12032          Air Flow Setpoint Maximum   471.946991
15  slipstream_internal  slipstream_hq  12033            Space Temperature Local    22.315313
16  slipstream_internal  slipstream_hq  12033  Space Temperature Setpoint Active    22.698660
17  slipstream_internal  slipstream_hq  12033          Air Flow Setpoint Maximum   235.973495
```

From here we can manipulate dataframes, and apply your rules:

1. ignore columns 0 and 1
2. use column 2 as `VAV_ID`
3. define which rows will be `Zone_Temps`, `Zone_Temp_Setpoints`, and `Air_Flows` based on column 3
4. keep values in column 4

```
>>> df = df.rename(columns={2: 'VAV_ID', 4: 'value'})
>>> df['col'] = df[3].map({
...    'ZN-T': 'Zone_Temps',
...    'Space Temperature Local': 'Zone_Temps',
...    'ZN-SP': 'Zone_Temp_Setpoints',
...    'Space Temperature Setpoint Active': 'Zone_Temp_Setpoints',
...    'CLG-MAXFLOW': 'Max_Clg_Flow',
...    'Air Flow Setpoint Maximum': 'Max_Clg_Flow',
... })
>>> df[['VAV_ID', 'col', 'value']]
   VAV_ID                  col        value
0      27           Zone_Temps    72.273071
1      27  Zone_Temp_Setpoints    70.000000
2      27         Max_Clg_Flow   580.000000
3      29           Zone_Temps    73.020958
4      29  Zone_Temp_Setpoints    69.750000
5      29         Max_Clg_Flow  1400.000000
6      30           Zone_Temps    71.638565
7      30  Zone_Temp_Setpoints    72.000000
8      30         Max_Clg_Flow   918.000000
9   12028           Zone_Temps    23.014437
10  12028  Zone_Temp_Setpoints    23.330000
11  12028         Max_Clg_Flow   660.725830
12  12032           Zone_Temps    22.482546
13  12032  Zone_Temp_Setpoints    22.307844
14  12032         Max_Clg_Flow   471.946991
15  12033           Zone_Temps    22.315313
16  12033  Zone_Temp_Setpoints    22.698660
17  12033         Max_Clg_Flow   235.973495
```

Finally we can use [`DataFrame.pivot()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.2.0/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) to transform our rows into columns as desired

```
>>> df.pivot(index='VAV_ID', columns='col', values='value').reset_index()
col VAV_ID  Max_Clg_Flow  Zone_Temp_Setpoints  Zone_Temps
0    12028    660.725830            23.330000   23.014437
1    12032    471.946991            22.307844   22.482546
2    12033    235.973495            22.698660   22.315313
3       27    580.000000            70.000000   72.273071
4       29   1400.000000            69.750000   73.020958
5       30    918.000000            72.000000   71.638565
```